# How to use the aspector gem to wrap class methods?

Tags: ruby, aop

I am using the ruby aspector gem to do some code instrumentation, but I need to instrument class methods in addition to instance methods. When I run the code below, I get

> Foo.bar(baz)

But I expected

> Foo.bar executed with result => Foo.bar(baz)
>
> Foo.bar(baz)

How do I get the expected result?

```
require 'aspector'
class Foo
  def self.bar(msg)
    "Foo.bar(#{msg})"
  end
end

class FooAspect < Aspector::Base
  around :bar, method_arg: true do |method, proxy, *args, &block|
    name = "#{self.class}.#{method}"
    result = proxy.call(*args, &block)
    warn "#{name} executed with result => #{result}"
    result
  end
end
FooAspect.apply(Foo)
puts Foo.bar("baz")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation is poor in Aspector, but you can always go to [spec/functionals](https://github.com/gcao/aspector/tree/master/spec/functionals) and try to find a solution.

About your case. Just use `class_methods: true` option when apply your aspect:

```
FooAspect.apply(Foo, class_methods: true)
```

Full code listing:

```
require 'aspector'

class Foo
  def self.bar(message)
    puts message
  end
end

class FooAspect < Aspector::Base
  around :bar, method_arg: true do |method, proxy, *args, &block|
    puts 'start'
    proxy.call(*args, &block)
    puts 'end'
  end
end

FooAspect.apply(Foo, class_methods: true)
Foo.bar('execute')
=> start
=> execute
=> end
```